# Reasoning/Intuition behind index formula

Tags: java, math

I was given this piece of code for analyzing:

```
private String type[] = {"Hearts","Spades","Clubs","Diamonds"};
private String rank[] = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace"};
private String deck[] = new String[52];


private void createDeck(){
    for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < type.length; j++){
            deck[type.length*i + j] = rank[i]+type[j];
        }
    }
}
```

It's a simple simulation of a deck of cards and I'm fully understanding how the arrays are working and are being populated through the looping logic. 
What I have trouble understanding though, is where the intuition and reasoning behind how the indexing of the array is done with: `type.length*i + j`

Upon analyzing the output of this, it's simple enough, you get increments of 1 for each loop around. Great. But I can't for the love of Java understand how the creator came to formulate this formula for something so simple as incrementing by 1 each time.

I'm not sure what I'm asking here... what's the reasoning/logic behind this simple formula? What can I do to get that kind of intuition when facing similar situations? It just seems completely pulled out of the blue from my perspective. I'm fairly familiar with algebra and calculus, but this is not something I would've been able to figure out with the mathematical knowledge that I have.

Thanks.

Comment: Think of the deck as a matrix, instead of a linear array. To be frank, at some point those expressions just become idiomatic and you don't think about how you got there too much :)

Comment: The alternative is to use `for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) deck[i]=rank[i/type.length]+type[i%type.length];` if you'd rather. [Test it here](https://ideone.com/kTyGJs). Bit harder to read though, and I doubt it has many advantages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's consider the order in which the cards are added to the array. Based on the given code, we are looping over the ranks, and for each rank, going over all types before moving on to the next rank. So the order is:

> 1 of hearts, 1 of spades, 1 of clubs, 1 of diamonds, 2 of hearts, ...

Now that we know in what order we want to add the cards, how do we know a card's index given its rank and type?

We have in order 4 cards of each rank: 4 cards of rank 1, followed by 4 cards of rank 2, 4 cards of rank 3, and so on. So a card of rank 8 for example should be added after at least 6*4 = 24 cards, **plus some offset**. And this offset depends on the card's type.

And that's pretty much it! Having `i` as an index of the ranks and `j` as one for the suits, we get that the index of a given card is:

```
type.length*i + j
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way of looking at it is that it is the reverse of applying the division (`/`) and remainder (`%`) operators.

```
   i = 34 / type.length = 34 / 4 = 8
   j = 34 % type.length = 34 % 4 = 2
```

So reversing that you get

```
   34 = type.length * i + j
```

which leads to

```
   deck[type.length * i + j] = rank[i] + type[j]
   deck[34] = rank[8] + type[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a linearisation of 4 * 13 Cartesian product (two dimensional values) in one array of 52 elements.

`i*4` goes in steps of 4, and `j` takes 0, 1, 2, 3. So the actual index goes in steps from 0 to 52-1.

A side note:

```
private String type[]
```

is C compatible syntax (from Java's early days). Normal would be:

```
private String[] type
```